# How to console.log the value of i in a for loop when catching error in an async function?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, variables, asynchronous, try-catch

Let's say that the for loop inside the function fails, and the function catches an error. How can i `console.log` the value of `i` at the moment when an error is catched?

```
async function loop(){

try{
for(let i = 0; i < 6; i++){

 

}

} catch(e){
  console.log("error" + e)
}



}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
async function loop(){
    let i;
    try{
        for(i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            // Example
            if(i === 3) {
                console.log(p); // Some undefined variable to throw an error
            }
        }
    } catch(e){
      console.log(`error ${e} i: ${i}`);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
    async function loop(){

      try{
      for(let i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        console.log(i);
        if(i == 4){
           throw Error(`item: ${i}`)
        }
      }

      } catch(e){
        console.log("error:" + e)
      }

    }

    loop();
```

Comment: this logs the value of i anytime and not only if there's an error!

Comment: Yes, is just to demonstrate that the loop breaks with the error

Comment: How can i console.log the value of i when I don't know the value it will throw an error on? @sonEtLumiere